# How can I sync all of my Email addresses (including Gmail addresses) using iCloud?

Tags: data-synchronization, icloud, email

I just got an iPad and I'm trying to sync all of my Email addresses across all of my devices, including my iMac and iPhone.

I already had an Apple ID and had iCloud set up for my iPhone and iMac, but when I went to set up my Email on my iPad it prompted me to create an @me Email address. So I did. But none of my Emails are syncing up with my iMac, and I thought the whole purpose of creating an @me account was so that all of my Emails would sync up through iCloud.

What I have is a couple of different Gmail accounts that I would like to sync up using iCloud. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Practically speaking, the answer would be no - iCloud doesn't "sync" multiple email accounts (this is built into iOS). @me.com email address is just like gmail - it is just another email account. If you *really* wanted to, you could have all your gmail forward to iCloud's @me.com email account, but that wouldn't be practical.

To have your Gmail accounts synced into your iPad, open **Settings**, on your iPad, tap **Mail, Contacts, Calendars**, select **Add Account**, for a Gmail account select **Gmail**, and enter your information in there. Repeat the process for every mail account you have. (You should notice your iCloud account in the list of email accounts when you first open it)

Answer (score 4):

First, you can **sync google's calendar/contacts/mail throughout all apple devices** just like you can with **iCloud**.

The integration if very easy and reliable. In general, the procedure is:

1. Go to the **System** or Application's *settings*
2. Select the **Accounts** section and add your preferred service.

> The easiest way to simplify and **centralize** your email services is
>   to forward all the mail to just one address.

This address you can then setup with all your devices to sync in the settings preferences.

Answer (score 2):

iCloud doesn't sync your email accounts, only your me.com account.

To truly sync the others you should have IMAP or Exchange accounts. You can then sync these with your devices, you can't do it with pop mail accounts.